# slick jquery plugin create more than 1 image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the plugin of kenwheeler, slick and i have no idea why my page has created more than one slide. As in the link below, there are just 4 images but 1 of them is repeated unexpectedly (you can see it at the end). Hope you can help me.Thanks a lot!

http://vietcruise.ngoisaoso.info/Ho-Chi-Minh-Excurtion/FULL-DAY-OF-SAIGON-DISCOVER-BY-CYCLO-68.html#book

My code:

```
<div class="slider">
            <div class="slider-for">                
                <!-- BEGIN: othersimg -->
                <div>
                    <img src="{IMG_SRC_OTHER}" alt="{TITLE}" style="height:500px; width: 100%"/>
                </div>
                <!-- END: othersimg -->     
            </div>      
            <div class="slider-nav">
                <!-- BEGIN: othersimg_thumb -->
                <div><a href=""><img src="{IMG_SRC_OTHER}" style="height:80px" /></a></div>
                <!-- END: othersimg_thumb -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .slick-prev{
                z-index: 99;
                left:20px!important
            }
            .slick-next{
                z-index: 99;
                right:20px!important
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function(){
            $('.slider-for').slick({
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              arrows: true,
              fade: true,
              asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
            });
            $('.slider-nav').slick({
              slidesToShow: 7,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              asNavFor: '.slider-for',
              dots: false,
              centerMode: false,
              focusOnSelect: true
            });
        });

        </script>
```

PHP code:

```
if( !empty( $otherimage ) )
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $otherimage as $otherimage_i )
        {
            if( !empty( $otherimage_i ) and file_exists( NV_UPLOADS_REAL_DIR . '/' . $module_name . '/' . $otherimage_i ) )
            {
                $otherimage_i = NV_BASE_SITEURL . NV_UPLOADS_DIR . '/' . $module_name . '/' . $otherimage_i;
                $xtpl->assign( 'IMG_SRC_OTHER', $otherimage_i );
                $xtpl->assign( 'num_itemimg', $i );
                $xtpl->parse( 'main.othersimg' );
                $xtpl->parse( 'main.othersimg_thumb' );
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $xtpl->parse( 'main.othersimg' );
        $xtpl->parse( 'main.othersimg_title' );
    }
```

Comment: Inspecting element shows you have 5 images rather than 4. Can you show us your html and code too ?

Comment: I also checked the divs generated by php code and there were just 4 ones.